# How to put variable length tick labels inside the plot canvas in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to turn this:[image: what it looks like now]
into something resembling this:[image: what it should look like]

All of the instructions I have come across just apply an offset to the label position and therefore only work if the labels are of a known width.

code to produce a similar plot than the example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
yvalues = [ 'short name', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.', 'slightly longer name' ]
xvalues = [ [1, 5], [3, 7], [2, 6] ]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(1280/fig.get_dpi(), 720/fig.get_dpi())
ax.axvline(40)
for i in range(len(yvalues)):
    ax.plot(xvalues[i], (yvalues[i], yvalues[i]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code example produces the second graph.  You say you want something "resembling" that second graph but do not describe what you want different.

Comment: The labels for the ticks on the Y-axis. I want them inside the plot canvas, not outside. The code produces a figure which has them on the outside, like the first image.

Comment: Your code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following two lines to your code

```
ax.tick_params(axis="y", direction="in", pad=-10)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(),ha="left")
```

will result in the following plot

[image]

Comment: The missing piece was `ha="left"`. Now I can't believe I never included "alignment" in any of the searches I made.