# How to make y axis text appear inside the plot while using data coordinates in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a plot where I display the maximum and minimum points in the plot in different colors. Since the plot is dynamic, sometimes the text appears right on top of the `ytick` *labels* which does not look good. I want to keep the `ytick`'s, so I thought of putting the text inside the plot.
However my x-axis is `datetime` variable, so providing the x,y position that is between the *first* and the *second* `xtick` is throwing me off.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218538/how-to-put-variable-length-tick-labels-inside-the-plot-canvas-in-matplotlib) but its for the whole axis.

Based on the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) I tried **axis coords** (0,0 is lower-left and 1,1 is upper-right) too, but the problem is that its difficult to come up with a proper pixel position that is both inside and top of the horizontal lines. Moreover I think it would be **difficult to maintain** since the data changes everyday.

I would like to stick to **data coordinates** since the data is dynamic.
Is it possible to do it using data coordinates?

Please use the following code I concocted for my situation -

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

x = ['2020-03-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05']
y = [1,2,3,4,5.8]
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': x, 'Y': y})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(x='X', y='Y', data=df)
show_point = 5.7
ax.axhline(show_point, ls='dotted')
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transData)
ax.text('2020-03-01', show_point, color="red", s=show_point, transform=trans, ha="right", va="bottom")

show_point2 = 1.7
ax.axhline(show_point2, ls='dotted')
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transAxes)
ax.text(0.05, 0.15, color="red", s=show_point2, transform=trans, ha="center", va="bottom")

plt.show()
```

**EDIT 1**
What it looks like now (in the real plot)-
[image]
Expected result -
[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your intended result?

Comment: @OregonTrail sure, let me first edit a picture. Give me 5-10 mins

Comment: @OregonTrail Added images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid all the axis transformation stuff while still working in data coordinates if you use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate`, something like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['2020-03-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05']
y = [1,2,3,4,5.8]
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': x, 'Y': y})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(x='X', y='Y', data=df)
show_point = 5.7
ax.axhline(show_point, ls='dotted')
ax.annotate(show_point, [ax.get_xticks()[0], show_point], va='bottom', 
            ha='right', color='red')

show_point2 = 1.7
ax.axhline(show_point2, ls='dotted')
ax.annotate(show_point2, [ax.get_xticks()[0], show_point2], va='bottom', 
            ha='right', color='red')

plt.show()
```

This will produce

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I understood what you have done here(putting the text above the first xtick). I tested it on my real plot too. Seems to work great !. However you will have to forgive me for waiting a bit for a potential answer using `ax.text` & transforms or at atleast a confirmation that it won't work that way. I will accept it shortly if I get no more replies! And BTW I don't think it needs ```from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()```

Answer (score 7):

The idea of using a blended coordinate system is correct. You can place the text at a y-coordinate in data coordinates and an x-coordinate in axes coordinates.

```
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transAxes, ax.transData)
ax.text(0.01, show_point, show_point, color="red", transform=trans, ha="left", va="bottom")
```

This particular blended transform is even built in, so you may also use

```
ax.text(0.01, show_point, show_point, color="red", transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
        ha="left", va="bottom")
```

Comment: I have never been so conflicted. Both the answers provided work. Your's works with my existing code and @William Miller made me learn how to use annotations which has its own uses. Since William provided the answer first, I will accept his. Hope you don't mind. You have my upvote too.

Comment: The main difference between the two answers will be obvious if you use the *zoom* or *pan* tool. Here the text would stay close the the axis, in the other answer the text would move around in x direction. (I don't mind you accepting any answer that is correct and answers the question, since that is how that feature is indeed meant to be used)

Comment: This is the better answer I think, only reason I provided the `annotate` approach was because OP mentioned positioning relative to the xticks - but that isn't really the best way if panning or zooming is involved.